# Odoo import use custom field as id

Tags: import, odoo, odoo-15

i want to update the product prices on odoo
when i export the data from the system to update it , it comes with
an extra field (id) from there i can update the prices by importing
the file again , how ever i have a csv file exported from another system
with products data with tow columns (name, price)
and when i try to import the file i get duplicated products
so i made  the product name **UNIQUE**
to avoid duplicates but i get anothor error that **product name already exists!!**

my question is:

how can i update my products prices using the uniqe field **name** as ID for importing

Comment: What Odoo version do you use?

Comment: odoo 15 community